# Use of Resources' image as background

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I've registered an image in the Resources as BG_1, when I set it as a panel's background it shows in the preview and generates this code

```
<Canvas.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/BG_1.jpg"/>
</Canvas.Background>
```

But on debug it throw an unmanaged exception and crashes on InizializeComponent() as if it can't find it.
I've tried application instead of siteoforigin too.

What's wrong? What's the best way to embed assets in a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the article [WPF Application Resource, Content, and Data Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it might help you